# Stored procedure to insert multiple rows into at least 2 tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert, bulkinsert

I have looked but not sure if it is possible.

I have a database of rates. A service has multiple tables involved and they are:

- option record - one for the service in OPT table
- validity record - one for each date range is valid, from and to, in OSR table
- actual rate - has a minimum of 12 records per OSR (date range), in OPD table

I have created an Excel report to calculate the required rates that need to e input into the system and this was uploaded to SQL and I have Insert statements to create the OSR records and OPD records and when run as standard query works a treat and is correct.

For other staff that are even less familiar with SQL I would like to find the best way for them to run the process to upload the rates with out having to run multiple queries.

I have NO idea about stored procedures so I was wondering if it is possible to have a stored procedure to be able to run the insert function? If it is could it be one stored procedure, or would I need 2 for each table? The OPT doesn't need to be created as this already exists, it is the date range and rates that I am looking at inserting.

I know I have not provided any specific scripts at this stage I would like just advise if it can be done first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPs are typically capable of batching multiple SQL statements - including `INSERT`s - so it is likely that you would only require one.  Having not specified the RDBMS you're using, it is difficult to give an authoritative answer.

Comment: Sorry it is SQL 2008 but I think you have answered my question. Thanks.  now I just have to figure out how to write it.